# Laravel Model, deleted callback not being called

Tags: php, laravel

im trying to run some additional code when a row is deleted using my Model. However the callback `statis::deleted` simply isn't being triggered.

**Controller:**

```
/**
 * @param Website $website
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function delete(Website $website, Request $request)
{

    $id = $request->input('id-value');

    WebsiteRedirects::query()->where(['website_id' => $website['id'], 'id' => $id])->delete();

    Session::flash('message', [ 'is-success' => [ '1 Redirect has been deleted!' ] ]);

    return back();

}
```

**Model:**

```
class WebsiteRedirects extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'website_redirects';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saved(function ($redirect) {
            PlannerStatus::status('redirect', $redirect->website_id, 1);
        });
        static::deleted(function($redirect) {
            dd('deleted');
            PlannerStatus::status('redirect', $redirect->website_id, 1);
        });
    }
    ...
```

`static::saved` works fine, and I insert using `query` too.

```
WebsiteRedirects::query()->create(
            [
                'website_id' => $website->id,
                'redirect_from' => $request->input('redirect-from'),
                'redirect_to' => $request->input('redirect-to')
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is not being called because you are not deleting the row via Eloquent. You are deleting the row directly, without fetching the result - therefor Eloquent can't run the deleted event.

You will have to fetch the model before deleting for the event to be triggered.

```
WebsiteRedirects::where(['website_id' => $website['id'], 'id' => $id])->first()->delete();
```

Add `first()` to retrieve the `WebsiteRedirect` before you run `delete()`

Comment: Just changed the delete line to `WebsiteRedirects::where(['website_id' => $website['id'], 'id' => $id])->delete();` and it still doesn't work. The `saved` one works and this also uses `query()`.

Comment: Thanks, using `WebsiteRedirects::query()` still seems to work first, just needed to add the `first()` to the end. I mainly add `query()` to stop PHPStorm shouting saying `Non-static method `.

Comment: @MartynBall Yea that should work aswell, I edited my answer accordingly. Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks! Will accept as answer as soon as it allows me.

Comment: Another quick question, i'm trying to delete all the rows which match a certain row, `WebsiteRedirects::query()->where(['website_id' => $website['id']])->delete();`. But of course I can't use `first()` here, as theres multiple rows. I tried `get()` and `all()` but can't use `delete()` after either of them?

Comment: If you want the deleted event to be ran then you would have to loop through them all and run delete on them individually.

Comment: Damn, I had a feeling i'd have to do this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
WebsiteRedirects::query()->where(['website_id' => $website['id'], 'id' => $id])
```

right before the `delete()` method, the instance of the object is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` not your model. wich will trigger the Eloquent delete (DB) not your model's one.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you would do something like:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$user->delete();
```